# Why ‘that which I burnt and that which I haven’t yet burnt’?

Tags: bitul-batel-null, bedikas-chametz

After burning the Chametz we say

> כָּל חֲמִירָא וַחֲמִיעָא דְּאִכָּא בִרְשׁוּתִי דַּחֲזִתֵּהּ וּדְלָא חֲזִתֵּהּ דַּחֲמִתֵּהּ וּדְלָא חֲמִתֵּהּ דְּבִעַרְתֵּהּ וּדְלָא בִעַרְתֵּהּ לִבָּטֵל וְלֶהֱוֵי הֶפְקֵר כְּעַפְרָא דְאַרְעָא. Any Chametz that I own... whether I burned it or not, is null and ownerless, like dust.

Why do we need to nullify burnt Chametz? If it’s burnt, it doesn’t need nullification!

Comment: Whose translation is that?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to burn all of the chometz you own.

Comment: Consider this translation instead https://www.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/117223/jewish/Chametzs-Final-Moments.htm

Comment: " If it’s burnt, it’s not la’achilas kelev". Have you seen some of the things that dogs eat??? They eat stuff that humans would consider disgusting. Toilet water is the least of it. Point is, just because something is burnt doesn't mean that a dog still won't eat it.

Comment: @DanF [Just because you have a dumb dog...](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56301/9682)

Comment: Cf. Pesachim 6b which poses a similar question regarding why we have to nullify at all, concluding that it's just in case you find a nice piece of cake that you want to keep. Perhaps you can say something similar here, just in case there's a nice piece of chametz that you thought was burned but wasn't?

Comment: @Dr. Shmuel and DonielF so say ‘whatever I haven’t burned, whether I know about or not’ which is basically what we say ‘what I saw and what I haven’t seen’.

Comment: DoubleAA what does ‘that which I have removed’ mean? That which I have removed from my possession? From existence? Either way, it doesn’t need bittul.

Comment: @DanF good point, I edited it out.

Answer (score 2):

You assume that לבער means "to burn", although it's R Yehuda opinion on Peshachim 21a, We don't accept his opinion, we accept the opinion that one can get rid of the *chametz* in many ways (burning is still preferred), so לבער  means to "to get rid of" in this connotation.

It's not the sole time that לבער does not mean "to burn".

Livestock sometimes called this way:

בראשית מה יז

> טַעֲנוּ אֶת בְּעִירְכֶם וּלְכוּ בֹאוּ אַרְצָה כְּנָעַן

Load your livestock, and go, come to Cennan

(tenth)ביעור" מעשר" is not that you need to burn the tenth, it means you have to give it.

(The holy corps of the seventh year) ביעור" פרות שביעית" - We say that you don't even have to destroy it, it's enough to lose possession of it

so it's possible, that one did ביעור of the *chametz*, but it's still exists.

Comment: If I have “destroyed” it, no matter what destroyed means, it doesn’t belong to me anymore. If it means literal destroying- it doesn’t belong to anybody. If it means just getting rid of it- it doesn’t belong to me anymore, because I got rid of it. Either way, *it’s not in my possession so it doesn’t need bittul.*

Comment: And if I haven’t destroyed it, it shouldn’t be part of this category, it should be part of the “or haven’t destroyed it” category.

Comment: @Loani You are right, I'll edit to make it right.

Answer (score 0):

A student asked the Netziv this question one time at Volozhin. He replied that the Gemara says if a building collapses on your chametz, "it's as if it was destroyed." However, you still have to nullify it!

He said the phrase "that I destroyed" refers to such a case.

Comment: The phrase in the OP is that I burned not that I destroyed

Comment: @Shalom in what way is it considered ‘destroyed’? Is there any nafka Mina? (except for this one obviously)

Comment: @DoubleAA that's a kashya on  the translation. Biur means "getting rid of."

Comment: @Shalom if part of your answer is the OP mistranslated something, you should explain that explicitly

Comment: @Shalom In what way is the chaometz under the collapsed building considered destroyed if not for biur? Are there any nafka Minos?